# Coloring each quadrant on a ggplot xy scatter according to a color scale specified given by a third variable. geom_rect R

Tags: r, ggplot2, background-color, scatter-plot

Objective:

1. Create the XY scatterplot of variables (xx,yy). Color the corresponding Cartesian quadrants according to a third variable's (return) median.
   I've created the color vector using colorRampPalette. The issue is that it is being read as continuous (though the vector is discrete).
2. Have the scatter points be blue (not labeled "blue")
3. Include a label on each quadrant according to dt.data[, quadrants] so that it is easy to identify what the area corresponds to. So the mark A or the top right, B on bottom right, etc.

This is the code I've written.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(
  xx = rnorm(40, 0, 2),
  yy = rnorm(40, 0, 2),
  return = rnorm(40, 1, 3))

## compute the range we're going to want to plot over
## in this case 50% more than the max value
RANGE <- 1.5 * dt[, max(abs(c(xx, yy)))]

## compute the medians per quadrant 
dtMedians <- dt[,
                .(med = median(return)),
                .(sign_x = sign(xx), sign_y = sign(yy))]

## set up some fake labels
dtMedians[, quadrant := letters[1:4]]

## compute a color scale for the medians and assign it
fcol <- colorRampPalette(c("#FC4445", "#3FEEE6", "#5CDB95"))
dtMedians[, col := fcol(4)[rank(med)]]
Mycol <- dt.Medians[, .(col)]

dt.rects2<- data.table(
  quadrant = letters[1:4],
  xmin= c(0,0,-RANGE, -RANGE),
  xmax= c(RANGE,RANGE,0,0),
  ymin= c(0,-RANGE,-RANGE,0),
  ymax= c(RANGE,0,0,RANGE))

dt.data <- merge(dtMedians, dt.rects2, by ="quadrant")

gg<- ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = dt.data, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = med ))
gg+
  scale_fill_manual(values = Mycol ) +
  labs(x="xx", y="yy", title='US. Growth Quadrant') +
  geom_point(data = dt, 
             aes(x = xx,
                 y = yy,
                 color = 'blue'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think the code could be much cleaner, I left it unchanged to the extent possible - there were a few mistakes (e.g., with the variables x and y) that I had to correct to be able to run the code. Now as to your questions:

1. You can tell R to treat a variable as a factor with `fill = as.factor(med)`. In addition, I had to adjust `scale_fill_manual(values = Mycol$col)` to select the colors defined in variable `col` of df `Mycol`.
2. To make the scatters blue, I took the `color = 'blue'` outside of the `aes()` in the `geom_point()`.
3. I used `annotate()` to label the corners of the plot, which relies on manually defining the x and y coordinates. I am sure there are other, potentially better (and automated) solutions out there.

Full code for the plot (taking your data):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = dt.data, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = as.factor(med))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Mycol$col) +
  labs(x="xx", y="yy", title='US. Growth Quadrant') +
  geom_point(data = dt, 
             aes(x = x,
                 y = y),
                 color = 'blue') +
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = 'A', x = 5, y = 5, size = 8) +
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = 'B', x = 5, y = -5, size = 8) +
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = 'C', x = -5, y = -5, size = 8) +
  annotate(geom = 'text', label = 'D', x = -5, y = 5, size = 8)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This does it. What does the `as.factor(med)` achieve differently? And how would you change the label of the "as.factor(med)" in the legend? Thanks

Comment: The variable `med` is continuous the way you constructed it. By using `as.factor()`, it is converted into a factor variable with four levels (since it takes four different values). For the legend, you can include `fill = "Legend title"` inside `labs()`.